# Prevent HAML snippets loading when using sass-mode and yasnippet

Tags: emacs, elisp, yasnippet

I'm using Emacs with sass-mode and yasnippet to edit .sass files. This is all working great and the snippets are expanding. But since sass-mode requires haml-mode the haml snippets are also loaded when editing sass files. This is rather annoying since the haml snippets are useless in sass.

I've checked my snippets directory for a .yas-parents file and didn't find one. And I've searched through the documentation and elisp code but a setting or function didn't jump out at me. When I run M-x yas-describe-table within a sass buffer I'm showon the expantion tables for both sass and haml.

Ideally I'd like to prevent the haml snippets from loading when opening when working on a sass buffer. But if I could setup some sort of hook to remove the haml table of snippets when sass buffers are loaded that would be good too.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea why the `sass-mode` major-mode is *derived* from `haml-mode`. It's that concept, which is wrong in my opinion, that's breaking yasnippet. See my comment in http://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way in yasnippets to do what you want. So you should open issue on `yasnippet` github repo requesting this feature.

As a temporary solution you can disable loading of `haml-mode` snippets in `sass-mode` by advising `yas--modes-to-activate` as follows. Remember this is **NOT** recommended

```
(eval-after-load "yasnippet"
  '(progn (defadvice yas--modes-to-activate (after my-simple-advise)
           (when (eq major-mode 'sass-mode)
             (setq ad-return-value (remove 'haml-mode ad-return-value))))

         (ad-activate 'yas--modes-to-activate)))
```

The above advises `yas--modes-to-activate` so that `haml-mode` is not returned as a mode to load when in `sass-mode`.

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you. I've just opened an issue with yasnippet https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/465 so perhaps we'll get an option for this.

Comment: Also your fix works perfectly with my version of yasnippet.  Version: 20140227.703